# BGE - Calculate Acceleration from Velocity

Tags: python, game-engine, physics, logic-bricks, mathematics

I need to calculate acceleration of my rigid-body object in Blender Game Engine.
What I did now is:

```
from bge import logic
from mathutils import Vector

if not "prevspeed" in own:
    own["prevspeed"] = Vector((0, 0, 0))
speed = ob.localLinearVelocity
acceleration = speed - own["prevspeed"] * logic.getAverageFrameRate()
own["prevspeed"] = ob.localLinearVelocity.copy()
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I need to know how to make it work correctly.

Comment: Be aware speed is not velocity (as mentioned in your code). Velocity is a vector (direction and length). Speed is the length of Velocity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I need to know how to make it work correctly."

that will take some work on your script.

First off, there are many problems with your script. The most obvious being a syntax error. you should have another `)` after `Vector((0, 0, 0)`. Second, you do not define `own` or `ob`. But the worst error, is you can not define a vector on a game property. There is no property type called *vector*

[image]

The five property types are Boolean, Integer, Float, String, and Timer. If you try to assign a vector to a game property, the only one that would come close to working is the String property, and that wouldn't do much in the realm of usefulness.

I would not actually use the method you are trying to use. I would calculate Acceleration like this:

```
import bge
from mathutils import Vector

controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
obj = controller.owner

previous_velocity = Vector(obj.worldLinearVelocity)

def main():
    global previous_velocity

    current_velocity = Vector(obj.worldLinearVelocity)

    acceleration = (current_velocity - previous_velocity) * bge.logic.getAverageFrameRate()
    print(acceleration)

    previous_velocity = current_velocity
```

Also, you must reference this bit of python by calling it from a module controller, not a script controller.

[image: qqq]

Comment: This script is not directly copied from the game code. In game code I store previouse speed in a class. Oh, and if you define property in python, it can be anything, because KX_GameObject is actually a dictionary that you can manipulate freely(try `print obj`).
However, it doesn't work for me this way.

Comment: Oh, and the end of the script - it wouldn't work without copy(). IDK why, but it just wouldn't.

Comment: OK! My problem was where I execute everything. I have fixed all now. I'll check your answer as correct anyways as it at least includes rightm math.

Comment: Some corrections: Since 2.49 you can store any object in a game property. A KX_GameObject is a class not a dictionary.